# SQL select request with different values in a java prepared statement

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, model-view-controller, junit

**Hi everyone !**

I am using JSP, mvc and JAVA and I am trying to display information from my database with a select * with different values in my where : "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lastname =' AND city ='" .

The problem is that when I test this request with JUnit I have an error near or at my first parameter in my WHERE.

PS : If I do a select request with one parameter in my where clause it works.

You will find below my code.

**My class with the request :**

```
public class CustomerDao extends DAO<Customer>{


 private static final String SQL_SELECT_Plus = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lastname =' AND city ='";



 public CustomerDao(Connection c) {
        super(c);
    }

 @Override
    public List<Customer> findByPlus(String lastname, String city) throws DAOException {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        System.out.println("test1");
        try {
            System.out.println("test2");

            /* Récupération d'une connexion depuis la Factory */

           System.out.println("test32");
            preparedStatement = this.initRequest(this.connection, SQL_SELECT_Plus + lastname + "'" + city + "'", false);
            System.out.println("test3");

            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("test4");

            /* Parcours de la ligne de données de l'éventuel ResulSet retourné */
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                customers.add(map(resultSet));
                System.out.println("test5");

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("EREUR");

            this.silentCloses(resultSet, preparedStatement, connection);
        }
        return customers;
        }
```

**My JUnit test :**

```
public class AccountControllerTest {

   CustomerController customerController = new CustomerController();


    @Test
    public void shouldReturnErrorInModel() {
       customerController.selectAction4("Dupont","Paris");

    }
```

**And the JUnit error :**

> test1 test2 test32 test3 EREUR
>   **fr.esipe.ing2.esibank.dao.DAOException:** > > **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near** >
>   **"Dupont" Position : 54 at** > > **fr.esipe.ing2.esibank.customer.dao.CustomerDao.findByPlus(CustomerDao.java:164)**
>     at
>   fr.esipe.ing2.esibank.customer.controller.CustomerController.selectAction4(CustomerController.java:97)
>     at
>   fr.esipe.ing2.esibank.account.AccountControllerTest.shouldReturnErrorInModel(AccountControllerTest.java:15)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at
>   or near "Dupont"   Position : 54  at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:420)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:305)     at
>   fr.esipe.ing2.esibank.customer.dao.CustomerDao.findByPlus(CustomerDao.java:153)
>     ... 25 more

Answer (score 0):

Your string concatenation results in a SQL Statement of: "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lastname =' AND city ='Dupont'Paris'"

You should never do String concatenation for SQL. This is how SQL injection happens.

You should use parameters in your SQL string

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lastname=:lastName AND city=:city";
NamedParameterStatement ps = new NamedParameterStatement(connection, query);
ps.setString("lastName", lastname);
ps.setString("city", city);
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for the fast answer. In reality my aim is to do a search by typing something in a search bar and this is why my where is like this. I put "Dupont","Paris" in my JUnit test just to be sure that the selectAction is working.  preparedStatement = this.initRequest(this.connection, SQL_SELECT_Plus + lastname + "'" + city + "'", false); lastname and city will be entered by the user.

Comment: ok. doesn't change my answer.  use prepared statement parameters.  Never use string concatenation.   read more: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077706/core-java/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.html

Comment: When I try to do as you told me I have this error for the method setString The method setString(int, String) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (String, String).  Sorry I am not a expert in java...lol

Comment: sorry, I had the wrong syntax. please read the article link I posted, it explains it in depth.

Comment: Okay no problem I will check it. But by using concatenation what I need to change to make it working please? I just want to test if my search with different parameter works :).

Comment: I updated the syntax in my answer. named parameters take a variable. So when the next user searches you just change the variable. What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks. But to use NamedParametersStatement I need to create a new class. I will try it tomorrow, but what I need to change in my request or in my prepared statement to succeed by using concatenation?